# how to use condition in linq while reading node from xml file

Tags: c#, xml, linq

how to add value of address and HomeAddress based on condition for Rule1 and Rule2.

**Xml File :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<File>
   <Data>
     <id></id>
     <name></name>
     <address></address>
     <HomeAddress></HomeAddress>
  </Data>
</File>
```

**C# code** 
[in reality xml is complex file]

```
XDocument xmlDocFinal = XDocument.Load(@"E:/Test.xml"); string[]
myCondition = {"Rule1","Rule2"};
foreach(string rule in myCondition)
{
    var dataList = (from root in xmlDoc.Descendants("File")
                    from Data in root.Elements("Data")
                    select new
                    {
                        // For 
                        Name = Data.Element("name").Value,
                        ID = Data.Element("id").Value,
                        // if rule1 then add Address otherwise ingnor  it
                        Address =Data.Element("address").Value 
                        // if rule2 then add HomeAddress otherwise ingnor  it
                        HomeAddress = Data.Element("HomeAddress").Value 
                    })
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Please format the code and actually describe the problem and ask a question.  It's not clear what you're trying to achieve or what's preventing that.

Comment: @David i am trying to get list in which  address and homeAdress will be added based on condition like if rule1 then  add address otherwise ignor it same for HomeAddress if rule2 then HomeAdress otherwise ignor this element value

Answer (score 1):

You can make in-line conditions with the [conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).  Something like this:

```
 Address = someCondition ? Data.Element("address").Value : string.Empty,
 HomeAddress = anotherCondition ? Data.Element("HomeAddress").Value : string.Empty
```

So if `someCondition` is `true` then `Address` is set to the value, otherwise it's set to a default value (here I use `string.Empty`, you can use whatever you like).  The same is true for setting `HomeAddress`.

---

**Edit:** Based on comments below, if you want to create two separate types then you're going to need two separate queries.  Something like this:

```
var dataListAddress = (from root in xmlDoc.Descendants("File")
                       from Data in root.Elements("Data")
                       where someCondition // first condition
                       select new
                       {
                           Name = Data.Element("name").Value,
                           ID = Data.Element("id").Value,
                           Address = Data.Element("address").Value 
                       }).ToList();
var dataListHomeAddress = (from root in xmlDoc.Descendants("File")
                           from Data in root.Elements("Data")
                           where anotherCondition // second condition
                           select new
                           {
                               Name = Data.Element("name").Value,
                               ID = Data.Element("id").Value,
                               HomeAddress = Data.Element("HomeAddress").Value 
                           }).ToList();
```

This is because the anonymous types in the `select` clause are different.  You could perhaps merge them into the same collection if it's a collection of something like `object` or maybe `dynamic`, but that could be unwieldy downstream when you need to use that collection.

Comment: i used this but i want to ignore that particular node i.e Address , it should not appear in dataList array .

Comment: @yashfale: At that point you're talking about creating two separate return types, which means you'd be creating two different `dataList` results..  What is the ultimate goal here?  What do you end up doing with `dataList`?

Comment: for first rule i will get like this datalist : [0] =Name, Id,address, for second rule i will get like this datalist : [0] =Name, Id,HomeAddress, actuly i am working with multiple xml files , having same node and diff node for other files i want to exclude this node at the time of creating datalist to avoid confusion while inserting data into database

Comment: @yashfale: I've updated the answer with another approach.  As mentioned, having two different types means having two different results.  What you ultimately do with those results is up to you and not really specified in the question.